# Trying to get iframe to scale with vimeo player

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm currently developing a website for someone. He is a cinematagropher, so his website primarily showcases videos. He has these videos hosted in Vimeo. I have a click function that if you click on a list of the videos, it loads the specific video in an iframe. The issue I'm having is that the iframe doesn't scale in different resolution screens.

I can get it to look pretty good in let's say a regular MacBook, but when it comes to an iPad or a smaller screen, it gives me these weird black borders. So I'm just curious if anyone knows any things I can implement to get this to scale with the frame?

[image: image, notice the black bars.]

Comment: Using HTML tables don't help and unless you're willing to redo the entire site to be responsive to different screens/resolutions, I'd recommend looking into a solution like (http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables) first.

Comment: Looking at the code on the page, you're actually not using an `iframe`, but instead a `video` tag.

Comment: @MikeKoch - He is, and the `<iframe>` has the class name of `PlayerFrame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4GNMd/

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/32346156?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=d0e774" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

div.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 45.1%;
}

div.container > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

div.container > div, iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. Thanks, the above code does help. The frames pretty much scale now with each different screen and browser which is a step in the right direction. The only issue im now finding is in safari/chrome for iPhone and ipad. I extended the width of each of my sections to 125% to maintain my style because after your implementation they only filled a portion of the screen then left a big whitespace. Would you per chance know a solution for getting these sections to appear with my design? Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: @user3286257 - I don't quite get the picture you are describing. A screenshot or demo would certainly be helpful.